# font with diagonal shadow

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

i would like to know the name of this classic font.The best part of this font is, it have diagonal shadow font.

Comment: I doubt that the shadow is "part" of the font as such; it is most likely added to the plain, light gray font. You can add shadows like that yourself.

Comment: @boblet there are fonts with the shadow -- http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/trend/ -- http://www.letterheadfonts.com/fonts/oldstock.php -- neither of these have the small serifs of the example, but I'm certain that must be part of the font. But you are right that it could easily be created for any font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "[Abraham Lincoln](http://francesmacleod.com/projects/font-design-abraham-lincoln/)", designed by [Frances MacLeod](http://francesmacleod.com/) and [available for purchase/download at LostType](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=Abraham%20Lincoln):

[image: Original screenshot with Abraham Lincoln overlayed]

*"[Abraham Lincoln](http://francesmacleod.com/projects/font-design-abraham-lincoln/)" at 136pt and "[Tracking](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WSC7A7BE38-87CE-4edb-B55A-F27458444E40a.html#WS23114CA0-BF63-4ba0-A550-5619E9842973)" increased to 92; the first "R" is slighly off - this easily fixed with some manual kerning; set in [Adobe Illustrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator)*

---

*Edit:* Here are some tutorials describing how to create the diagonal line pattern used in the shadow:

- http://forums.adobe.com/thread/508558
- http://www.shutterstock.com/blog/2010/02/how-to-create-a-diagonal-stripe-pattern-in-illustrator/
- http://bryan.parno.net/thoughts/?p=80
- http://www.bittbox.com/illustrator/how-to-create-a-seamless-diagonal-pattern-in-illustrator